# can't connect to mysql from android device

Tags: android, mysql

On my tablet, I am using a simple app from android app store to access mysql database on my PC (mysql manager). It fails saying:

> error.communication failure.

The last packet successfully sent to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
The driver has not received any packets from the server"

My firewall port 3306 is opened.
I have also granted permissions in mysql:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Access to `mysql` in my PC (localhost), works fine.
My PC is running on windows 7 and I am using the latest `mysql` workbench (version 6.0).
I am trying to connect through my wi-fi router.

I tried giving theses IPs for my PC on my android device:

```
127.0.0.1
10.0.0.1
```

Can you please advise me what else should I do in order to be able to access the mysql database on my PC from my tablet?

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem? If so check as "correct", if not tell me what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution Intranet/Lan (probably wi-fi):

If your Android Device is on *LAN NetWork* (probably wi-fi), you have to use the "lan ip".

1. Get the ip (local ip/lan ip) of your PC (something like
   192.168.1.101 or 10.0.0.101 or 10.1.1.12)
2. In your App (on android device) access something like 192.168.1.101:3306
3. Tip: recommend setting (manually) the IP of your computer because the router wont change the IP.

For get IP, see:

1. Open CMD
2. Type "ipconfig" (without quotation marks)
3. Press "Enter"
4. Your ip, subnet, mask and default gateway will be returned to you
5. Copy IP by the line `IPv4 Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`
6. Assuming you have returned something like "192.168.1.113"
   you must access the address to your "android device" like this: `192.168.1.113:3306`

Read about "local ip/Private addresses": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#IPv4_private_addresses

> Note: 10.0.0.1, 10.1.1.1, 192.168.0.1, 192.168.1.1 are IPs privates from ROUTER and non-PC, ie they will never be assigned to other computers because they belong to the router

### Emulator:

Running both MysqlServer and Emulator in you computer 127.0.0.1:(port)

The 10.0.2.2 (ie 10.0.2.2:3306) is the solution to that problem.

The emulator runs on a "virtual network", ie is not in the same network as your router.

### Emulator Networking details:

1. 10.0.2.1    Router/gateway address
2. 10.0.2.2    Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)
3. 10.0.2.3    First DNS server
4. 127.0.0.1   The emulated device's own loopback interface

Read: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

### 127.0.0.1

127.0.0.1 accesses only the localhost, ie when trying to access localhost with the emulator you try to open own emulator instead of the PC.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: thanks for your answer.
first i want to clarify that i am not working with an emulator. i am working with a real Andriod device. 
besides that i have tryed using th ip:10.0.2.2 as you suggested, and now i get a different error message: "Mysql manager isn't responding. Do you want to close it?"
any idea why it is still not working?

Comment: mysql server is on your computer or on a server?

Comment: mysql server is on my computer

Comment: your android is in a lan network or a virtual network (typically using ADT when connecting the USB cable)?

Comment: i think it is a lan. i am connecting my android device (wireless) to my wi-fi router.

Comment: Note: 10.0.0.1, 10.1.1.1, 192.168.0.1, 192.168.1.1 are IPs privates from ROUTER and non-PC, ie they will never be assigned to other computers because they belong to the router

Comment: Please tell me if you have any doubts

Answer (score 0):

First check on to my.ini file the proper configuration.

skip-networking=0
skip-bind-address

This 2 items must be commented with a # at the beginning onf the line.
Disable firewall on your windows, windows defender or antivirus.
Grant the acces to the user on your DB from any access point using the % wildcard.

Check the ipv4 ip from your computer/laptop, becauses this is the ip that your going to use on the android sql app as SERVER. Check the port used for mysql (xampp,wamp, etc) usually is 3306, enter the proper port from on the android app.

With this, everything should be working fine.

Sometimes is the ip the one that is failing on our app config.