# Can't connect to MYSQL from another device on the same network

Tags: mysql

The problem is when I'm trying to connect remotely on the same network to MYSQL DB it just prints out:

> Communications link failure. The last packet sent successfully to the
>   server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets
>   from the server.

If it matters, I've moved to another place lately where I live now. 
At the previous place, It worked perfectly. Maybe you can guess some troubles using this info (So I guess there's nothing about DB issues)

```
skip-networking
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

- The above things are commented.
- I can successfully ping from another device to the device where DB is located and vice versa
- I use port 3306 and 127.0.0.1 ip to connect remotely on the same network.
- I use such device as phone and application RemoDB to connect to DB remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer using [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490453/cant-connect-to-mysql-from-android-device?rq=1).
I shouldn't use 127.0.0.1 but IP of the device where DB is located.
Sorry for a possible duplicate.

Comment: Also you shouldn't be using `skip-networking`, I think.

Comment: And you could use 0.0.0.0 for the ip address.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, I've commented `skip-networking`. Thank you for your attention